# Multiple dependent dropdowns for data filtration in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a table of a portfolio of companies and their projects, now I want to create three dropdowns that are dependant and according to which the data should get fetched, here all the dropdowns must be dependent and self-sufficient at the same time, i.e. they should fetch data according to their parameter and also when they are applied together as well. let me give you a snapshot of what I require! let's take a 5x5 grid where first 2 columns are 'Industry' and 'Company Name' and then rest are collaterals like 'Web Portfolio', 'Landing Pages', and 'Brand Identity', I want three dropdowns working

1. Industry filter - should return all the companies in a specific industry
2. Company filter - shoud return all the collaterals for a company in a specific industry
3. Collaterals filter - should return a specific column with their respective company names

Here the catch is all dropdowns should work and the last dropdown should have the value of headers of columns except for first 2 i.e. Industry and Company as a search parameter

[Here's screenshot of Google sheet, where I'm attempting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slK3N.png)

[SheetLink]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zelGmvl878brKZ8xJOLJCJVTYL6dX8x30eGsZv0tiq8/edit#gid=271482903

Used this formula to fetch value:

=QUERY(A3:H9, "SELECT * WHERE Col1 = '"&A2&"' AND Col2 = '"&B2&"' AND Col"&MATCH(C2, 2:2, 0)&" <> ''", 1)

But it's not returning any hyperlinked text instead returning plain text

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing additional information!  As to your question...Sadly query will only return one data type and won't be able to function as requested. I'm sure there are many different ways to return the result you are looking for.  I used a [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) method in my example.

```
    =Filter({{A3:B9},Indirect(ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(C2:H2=C1, CHAR(COLUMN(C1:H1) + 64), ""))
)&3&":"&ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(C2:H2=C1, CHAR(COLUMN(C1:H1) + 64), ""))
)&9)},A3:A9=A1, B3:B9=B1)
```

It takes a custom array based on your selection.  `ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(C2:H2=C1, CHAR(COLUMN(C1:H1) + 64), "")` returns the Column letter to be used in the [Indirect formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en).  All you will need to adjust is the range to match the range you are trying to filter.

```
 Indirect(ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(C2:H2=C1, CHAR(COLUMN(C1:H1) + 64), ""))
)&3&":"&ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(C2:H2=C1, CHAR(COLUMN(C1:H1) + 64), ""))
)&9)
```

This will return the column reference of the selected value in C1.  From your example, if "Brand Identity" is selected, then The formula would return `Indirect(E3:E9)`.  Good luck with your project!

Edit:

Based on your feedback, here are two Updated options:

Option 1 Returns NA if Collaterals field is empty for the filter.

```
=Filter({{A3:B9}, {IFNA(INDEX(C3:H9, 0, MATCH(C1, C2:H2, 0)))}}, (A3:A9=A1)+(ISBLANK(A1)),(B3:B9=B1) +(ISBLANK(B1)),IFNA(INDEX(C3:H9, 0, MATCH(C1, C2:H2, 0)))<>""
)
```

Option 2 Returns all values even if blank:

```
=Filter({{A3:B9}, {IFNA(INDEX(C3:H9, 0, MATCH(C1, C2:H2, 0)))}}, (A3:A9=A1)+(ISBLANK(A1)),(B3:B9=B1) +(ISBLANK(B1))
)
```

To make these options work as intended, all you need to do is clear the Industry cell in A1 and/or the Company cell in B1 when you want to select all.  If they are blank, then it will filter based on the other selected criteria only.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the reply, for the second part of your solution I was able to fetch the result using the following :

=IFNA(INDEX(C3:H9, 0, MATCH(C1, C2:H2, 0)))

But here I would also want to get the corresponding company names, that's where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: I just noticed that I've forgotten to add significant detail, i.e. all the Dropdown should work independently and together at the same time, e.g. their independent working should be as follows

1. Industry filter - should return all the companies in a specific industry
2. Company filter - should return all the collaterals for a company in a specific industry
3. Collaterals filter - should return a specific column with their respective company names

Therefore if I select any value in "C1" it should fetch all Collaterals along with their company names.

Comment: @Kartikey Just added the edits requested.  Good luck!